# I am new to programming and I found a code which I do not know what language it is using. I think its Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Limited knowledge is regretted and explanation of the code or the name of the language is appreciated a lot. Thank you!

```
var myNickName='-undefined-';    
if($("a#jsid-my-profile").length)   
    {
    myNickName=$("a#jsid-my-profile").attr("href").replace("/u/","");
    }
```

Comment: it's javascript, and uses the jQuery "library"

Comment: Please don't ask this type of question here. If you get problem with your code, then ask. Thanks.

Comment: thanks i will delete it. lol

Answer (score 2):

Looks like JavaScript to me.

Specifically it's code using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Javascript and jQuery library.

I must point out strange value assignment:

```
var myNickName='-undefined-';
```